# Delete multiple points (vertexes) in powerpoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

I want to modify a powerpoint figure ([a chromatogram](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/69/Hplc-perfume-chromatogram.png)) imported from another application.
The figure is made of hundreds/thousands of points.
I want to delete some sections of the figure.

I can delete points one by one with *right-click* -> *delete point* but when the line section to delete is large and has many points it takes hours.

Is there some way to delete groups of (consecutive) vertexes in one only action ?

Comment: None that I know of; faced with the problem, I'd copy/paste the shape into CorelDraw or Illustrator or some other capable vector editing program and modify it there.  Draw even has a feature that automatically simplifies complex curves for you (by deleting unnecessary points).  It's not infallible but it generally works VERY well.

Comment: @SteveRindsberg Thanks Steve. I will try that

Answer (score 2):

I figured out a cool hack to solve this. When there are tons of points in the middle of a shape, I just draw another simple shape on top of the giant mess and then do a union of both shapes. The simple shape's points then delete the mess underneath. It's kind of like using an raster eraser on a vector image.

Comment: Can you explain exactly how to do a “union” between two shapes in PowerPoint, and how “doing a union” causes vertices to be deleted? (I hope you aren’t just talking about *hiding* part of an object by putting another object on top of it.) Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 1):

This won't delete multiple points at once but, if you hold the CTRL key down while hovering over a point, you will see a small "x".  Left Click to delete the point then continue to move to the next point and the next "x" to delete.

Comment: thanks, actually this is what I do to delete point by point. the question was how to delete several at the same time.